# how to decode email subject using email.Header.decode_header when then return is (decoded_string, None)

Tags: python, email, character-encoding, mime

I am trying to decode some emails for different charsets
Normally I can deal with it by using email.Header.decode_header,the second return value is the charset of the decoded_string,I can decode the string by it,but for some subjects,the second value is None,and the decoded_string is unreadable,but I don't know the charset of it ,so I can't decode it properly.

I find a way to deal with it by using the get_charsets()，and use the first not None value,It works fine now ,but I'm not sure this is the right way to do it

As I know,the email parts should have its charset information by the MIME standard,but since the one don't have,what should I do? Or there is a default charset to use when it comes to this situation?